# What is equivalent LDAP attributes for Active Directory

Tags: windows, perl, active-directory, ldap

What is equivalent LDAP attributes for Active Directory

I am looking for password using [Net::LDAP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::LDAP).

I dont know to how to set the user password using Net::LDAP

Comment: I've never used Net::LDAP but I have worked with LDAP and AD to create accounts and wasn't able to set or change passwords via LDAP only through other means (like use command, win32, wmi, powershell, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful article from Microsoft with some sample code that you might be able to adapt:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269190/how-to-change-a-windows-active-directory-and-lds-user-password-through

The essential attribute, it seems is: unicodePwd
  (a.k.a. Unicode-Pwd 
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680513(v=vs.85).aspx
  )

Also note some cautions and advice from this answer:  https://serverfault.com/questions/423345/changing-active-directory-password-over-ldap-using-passwd-ldappasswd-samba

AD attribute names with cross reference of LDAP attribute names 
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx